# Can't pinvoke libc function from .NET core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, pinvoke, .net-core, libc

I'm really enjoying the dotnet core possibilities, but there are certain problems on Linux platform.

I was working with `P/Invoke` stuff. It's fine on Windows, but when I tried to call function from `libc`on Linux - I've got a problem:

> Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so': The specified module could not be
>   found.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I've tried two ways (source code http://pastebin.com/HDTnrM0a):

- `[DllImport("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so")]`
- and just `[DllImport("libc.so")]`

Bot don't work and gave the same error. I've searched the certain file and it DOES EXIST:

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01:/home/projects/pinvoke1# find / -name "libc.so"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
```

PS, proof of using both variants:
[image]

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/79d44f202e4b6d000ca6c6885a24549a55db38f1/src/System.Console/src/Interop/Interop.manual.Unix.cs) suggests removing ".so" may help.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeap, it helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ".so" from the DllImport line

```
[DllImport("libc")]
```

(The answer was shared in the comments by Jeroen but reflecting it here in the answer section so this question can be marked as answered)