# Unable to load DLL dotnet core

Tags: macos, pinvoke, .net-core, dllimport

I am struggling with using P/Invoke with dotnet core preview4. The reason I am using P/Invoke is so that I can more finely control how a file is opened on Mac and Linux (certain flags are not supported after looking through source), especially since these two platforms are what I am testing on. I have tried several methods to try and use the dylibs, but nothing works. Here is what I have tried:

- Absolute path to dylib in `DllImport`
- Made sure dylib and its dependencies have an `@rpath` on mac
- tried doing `dotnet publish` according to another SO question
- [tried comment of this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563549/cant-pinvoke-libc-function-from-net-core-on-linux)

I think I may have tried other things, but I likely forgot. I am really at a lose as to what I could be doing wrong. [Project link](https://github.com/czifro-tech/mudt/tree/master/fsharp). To recreate:

- `dotnet restore` both `src` and `test` in `fsharp` directory
- `cd fsharp/`
- `sh build-native.sh`
- `cd` to test directory
- `dotnet run -- 3.2`

My dev env is:

```
OS => macOS Sierra
dotnet version => preview4-004233
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot the error message:

```
Error Message:
 System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'MUDT.Native.Apple': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Stack Trace:
   at MUDT.IO.FileStreamHelper.OpenApple(String filename, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at MUDT.IO.FileStreamHelper.openHandle(String filename, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at MUDT.IO.FileStreamHelper.getUnixFileStream(String filename, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize)
   at MUDT.IO.MemoryMappedFile.partitionFile@95.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MUDT.IO.MemoryMappedFile.partitionFile(Boolean isRead, MemoryMappedFileStateConfig config)
```

GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/8790

Comment: We have no code, and no error messages

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sorry about that just added error message. I hyperlinked text at beginning of question. Sorry if `am working on a thesis for my MS degree` seems useless, but I figured context as to why I would choose to do `P/Invoke` was necessary.

Comment: Why is there a Linux tag. Can't you just provide a clean mcve and ask about a single execution environment. Its much better if we don't have to extract this information.

Comment: I'll just remove the linux tag